# Is it right way to calculate pdf

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

Which of these is the right way to calculate pmf.
P(X=0) = (5/6)^4 or 
P(X=0) = (number of ways of choosing 4 out of 25)/ (number of ways of choosing 4 from 30)

Answer (score 2):

We are choosing **without replacement**. There are 
$$\dbinom{30}{4}\tag{1}$$ 
equally likely ways to choose $4$ stoves. Let $0\le k\le 4$. The number of ways to choose $k$ defectives **and** $4-k$ non-defectives is 
$$\dbinom{5}{k}\dbinom{25}{4-k}.\tag{2}$$
This is because there are $\binom{5}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ defectives, and for **each** of these ways there are $\binom{25}{4-k}$ ways to select the non-defectives that will join them.

For the probability that $X=k$, divide (2) by (1).

**Remark:** The random variable $X$ of the problem has **hypergeometric** distribution.

If the manager were choosing from an enormous supply, with probability $\frac{5}{30}$ that an individual stove is defective, we could safely use a "with replacement" model. Then the probability of exactly $k$ defective would have for all practical purposes **binomial** distribution, with 
$$\binom{4}{k}\left(\frac{5}{30}\right)^k \left(\frac{25}{30}\right)^{4-k}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I considered the case when there are no defectives. Make sense. I missed the point "without replacement".

Comment: You are welcome. And I missed the fact that yours was a sample calculation and not the general formula.